# Facebook's keyhash for android suddenly showing error : "invalid key hash"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash

I have an app that still in development (not in store yet). I have created 2 keyhashs, one for development and the other one is for release. This apps is working great, means i can login with `Facebook`.

Today, my apps suddenly cant login with `Facebook`. Its always showing `invalid key hash. "MY DEVELOPMENT KEY HASH" does not match any stored key hashes`.

I checked my `developers.facebook` account and found out i havent create any development key (only release key) **but** it used to be working. So i run this on my ubuntu terminal :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

And got my key hash. The funny thing is the keyhash generated in the terminal is **same** as "MY DEVELOPMENT KEY HASH" showed in the error message, **but** the one generated in the terminal have an extra `=` at the end of the key hash. I tried to add this development key hash but still no luck.

To summary my problem, my apps used to can login with `Facebook` but suddenly an invalid keyhash error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I believed theres a bug in `developer.facebook`. I need to **copy-paste** my development keyhash to the release key hash, so i have 3 keyhashs showed in the `quick start` (two in the `settings` tab, instead of one because the development keyhash is only visible in the `quick start` by default - thats why i copy-paste it).

And if you cant find where to put/find the development keyhash, you need to click `quick start` on the upper-right corner of `android` in the `settings` tab.

I tried my best to explain this. Feel free to comment if you have some questions.